# Can't insert a number into a char16_t-based custom C++ ostream/streambuf

Tags: c++, c++11, mingw, iostream, g++4.8

I have written a custom `std::basic_streambuf` and `std::basic_ostream` because I want an output stream that I can get a JNI string from in a manner similar to how you can call `std::ostringstream::str()`. These classes are quite simple.

```
namespace myns {

class jni_utf16_streambuf : public std::basic_streambuf<char16_t>
{
    JNIEnv * d_env;
    std::vector<char16_t> d_buf;
    virtual int_type overflow(int_type);

public:
    jni_utf16_streambuf(JNIEnv *);
    jstring jstr() const;
};

typedef std::basic_ostream<char16_t, std::char_traits<char16_t>> utf16_ostream;

class jni_utf16_ostream : public utf16_ostream
{
    jni_utf16_streambuf d_buf;

public:
    jni_utf16_ostream(JNIEnv *);
    jstring jstr() const;
};

// ...

} // namespace myns
```

In addition, I have made four overloads of `operator<<`, all in the same namespace:

```
namespace myns {

// ...

utf16_ostream& operator<<(utf16_ostream&, jstring) throw(std::bad_cast);

utf16_ostream& operator<<(utf16_ostream&, const char *);

utf16_ostream& operator<<(utf16_ostream&, const jni_utf16_string_region&);

jni_utf16_ostream& operator<<(jni_utf16_ostream&, jstring);

// ...

} // namespace myns
```

The implementation of `jni_utf16_streambuf::overflow(int_type)` is trivial. It just doubles the buffer width, puts the requested character, and sets the base, put, and end pointers correctly. It is tested and I am quite sure it works.

The `jni_utf16_ostream` works fine inserting unicode characters. For example, this works fine and results in the stream containing "hello, world":

```
myns::jni_utf16_ostream o(env);
o << u"hello, wor" << u'l' << u'd';
```

My problem is as soon as I try to insert an integer value, the stream's bad bit gets set, for example:

```
myns::jni_utf16_ostream o(env);
if (o.badbit()) throw "bad bit before"; // does not throw
int32_t x(5);
o << x;
if (o.badbit()) throw "bad bit after"; // throws :(
```

I don't understand why this is happening! Is there some other method on `std::basic_streambuf` I need to be implementing????

Comment: I'm not too sure why this is happening but I believe it is because you need to define an overload for integral types. It works when you do a cast: `o << (char16_t)x; // works`

Comment: There are templated insertion operators which match my statements though. It would make no sense to define these operators and have them just set the bad bit!

Comment: The problem doesn't have to do with anything you've *done* here. I've even implemented my own stream buffer and I had the same problem.

Comment: I got a few minutes to look at it in the debugger. I'm on MinGW/gcc 4.8.1 and the `basic_ostream` has a member called `_M_num_put` which is NULL, which is resulting in an exception. Not clear why it's NULL or how I can initialize it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the answer is that `char16_t` support is only partly implemented in GCC 4.8. The library headers don't install facets needed to convert numbers. [Here is what the Boost.Locale project says about it](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_48_0/libs/locale/doc/html/status_of_cpp0x_characters_support.html):

> ### GNU GCC 4.5/C++0x Status
>
> GNU C++ compiler provides decent support of C++0x characters however:
>
> Standard library does not install any std::locale::facets for this
>   support so any attempt to format numbers using char16_t or char32_t
>   streams would just fail. Standard library misses specialization for
>   required char16_t/char32_t locale facets, so "std" backends is not
>   build-able as essential symbols missing, also codecvt facet can't be
>   created as well.
>
> ### Visual Studio 2010 (MSVC10)/C++0x Status
>
> MSVC provides all required facets however:
>
> Standard library does not provide installations of std::locale::id for
>   these facets in DLL so it is not usable with /MD, /MDd compiler flags
>   and requires static link of the runtime library. char16_t and char32_t
>   are not distinct types but rather aliases of unsigned short and
>   unsigned types which contradicts to C++0x requirements making it
>   impossible to write char16_t/char32_t to stream and causing multiple
>   faults.